# What does "Only every time I see you" mean?

Tags: meaning

In opening scene from *Memento* (2000), memory loss Leonard meets Teddy at a store:

> Leonard: It's Leonard......like I told you before.
>
> Teddy: Did you? I must have forgot.
>
> Leonard: I guess I've already told you about my condition.
>
> Teddy: **Only every time I see you**.

What does "Only every time I see you" mean?

Comment: I haven't seen the film, but presumably Teddy's first response is sarcastic. Leonard explains about his amnesia every time they meet; _only_ is also sarcastic.

Comment: Can you explain what your problem is a bit more. I assume you know the meaning of the six words involved?

Comment: @KateBunting I didn't know "only" used as sarcastic way.

Comment: Teddy might be expected to say "Only once" or "Only a few times" - putting _only_ before _every time_  emphasises the fact that he finds it irritating to be told the same thing so often.

Comment: Me: have I told you how I played Julius Caesar in the school play? My wife: only every time I mention theatre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common form of sarcasm, deliberately violating the "[co-operative principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle)" or "Gricean maxims", to emphasise a point.

Consider the more straight-forward phrase "you only say it on Mondays" - the implication is that the other six days a week, it is not mentioned.

This can be extended to "you only say it six days a week" - this is still *logical*, because it excludes one day, but is beginning to sound sarcastic, because we expect "only" to refer to a *minority* of cases, not a *majority*.

Taken to the extreme, we get "you only say it every day" - here, the expectation of the word "only" is completely subverted, underlining the sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

You can watch this scene [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJECwNvHj3I&ab_channel=UnofficialMedia).

> Ah well, only every time I see you.

Teddy jokingly confirms that Leonard reminds him of the condition every time they meet.

I see it as a friendly "I don't mind hearing it again (even though I have heard it many times before)" remark.

*Only* also could be seen sarcastically, which would imply a slight annoyance.